# C# Entity Framework 4.1 dbset binding to DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-4.1

I have a EF code-first generated list of objects which is being accessed without issue via the context.

One property in the class in question is actually a reference to another class.

When I bind this to the datagridview, all columns show fine except for the references, which come up as a string "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact_43342..... long number".

Firstly, what i would really like here is the Contact Name or some other description to come up in this column.

Second, I would also like to be able to change the name of the column description to a more human friendly name, at the moment all column names are set to the class property names. It would be nice to edit the columns in advance, is it possible if among the columns can be done at design time?

Finally, and perhaps most complex, when I have an object which references other objects (for example my Invoice class has a Contact property as a foreign key) I would also like to have drop down combo box with a list of foreign key objects which I can select from. Direct editing with a combo box column in the datagridview would be great, however I am confused with how to populate the combo box with the Contact names and more importantly how to set the contact name to a specific object reference after the selection has been made (after all, the combo box displays names as strings where as the Invoice object expects a reference to an actual instantiated class).

Any ideas on how I can achieve the above?

Code is at the end of the post.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public Guid InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public Guid ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; } // lazy loading with virtual

    public Contact()
    {
      Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    }
}

public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

// and in the main form function after loading the context i bind the data to the grid view as follows:
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.modelContext.Invoices.Local;
```

Comment: Just override ToString() on your contact class. You are getting the default which is the name of the class....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson thanks Tony that answered my first question, thanks for your help. If you know about questions two and three would be great! Regards.